# Jquery Validate ckedior and ignore hidden fields on same form

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, ckeditor

CKEditor and hidden Field on same Form..

i used **ignore : [ ]**  and **ignore : ':hidden'** on validate...

but not working properly ....

```
$("#testform").validate({
                ignore: [],
                        rules :{    
            txt : "required",
             question: {
                    required: function() {
                        CKEDITOR.instances.question.updateElement();
                    }
                },              
            txt1 : "required",          
        }           
        });
```

**How to validate Ckeditor and ignore hidden fields?**

**See Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/UI_Designer/qu2borh1/**

Comment: `ignore: []` is telling the plugin to ignore **nothing**.  `ignore: ':hidden'` is telling the plugin to ignore **hidden elements but that's already the default** behavior.   You have to take the time to learn about what you are doing so you can better understand why it's not working as expected.

Comment: @user10 Regarding your latest question you just deleted. Check this link: http://jsfiddle.net/pd8wgvLq/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to fix it use ignore: ".hide"

or for ignore : ':hidden' to work change the type of the input in hidden

```
$("#testform").validate({
                ignore: ".hide",
                        rules :{    
            txt : "required",
             question: {
                    required: function() {
                        CKEDITOR.instances.question.updateElement();
                    }
                },              
            txt1 : "required",          
        }           
        });
```

Comment: Finally the great great R&D comes to an end with just a small line .... Thanks Alottt bro